# How do I disable MFA for a specific user in my Cognito User Pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication

I'm using AWS Cognito for my web-app's authentication, it works well.

Recently, we've decided to enable MFA for the User Pool which is attached to the app<sup>(*)</sup>. This works well.

We have a 'generic' user account which we like to keep logged-in to the web-app for demo purposes and we would like MFA to be disabled for this specific user account only.

I've attempted the instructions in this article, but to no avail:

https://saturncloud.io/blog/amazon-cognito-require-phone-verification-but-not-mfa

There is no 'disable MFA' for this particular user:
[image: Screencap of AWS Cognito user settings (it does not include an option to select 'Disable MFA' (or similar) for that particular user).]

Is this because the User Pool is set to require MFA and cannot be overridden at the user level?

**How do I disable MFA for a specific user in my AWS Cognito User Pool?**

<sup>(* Yes, I know we should enable MFA quickly, but it's a prototype app so we're not concerned about the timing of MFA yet).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

> Is this because the User Pool is set to require MFA and cannot be overridden at the user level?

Correct. MFA settings for Amazon Cognito can be configured as off, optional, or required,  user pools. If MFA is off, then no users are prompted with for MFA during sign-in. If MFA is optional, then MFA is added at the user level.

You'll need to set it to optional, to disable it for this user. But then it's optional for everyone.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-mfa.html#user-pool-configuring-mfa

Comment: Any way to set it for all users except one? Like do it the other way around: leave it optional for the User Pool, then have it required for each user (except one)?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Required means not optional, even for one.

Comment: You could consider generating the MFA token programmatically, from a stored MFA secret key and use it to authenticate the demo user https://earthly.dev/blog/multi-factor-auth/